# pandas datareader Code works in Colab but not spyder

Tags: python, pandas, spyder, stock, pandas-datareader

I am making a program to read stock data using stooq and pandas data reader, it's working for me in colab, but when I copy paste the same code into spyder it returns an empty data frame. I did a factory reset in each, and got the same result. I am very confused with this and if anybody else could share insight it would be very appreciated, here's the code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import parser
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import time

date = "January 10, 2022 10:00"
date_time = parser.parse(date)
time = date_time.hour + date_time.minute/60
if time <= 9: OPEN_DAY = datetime(date_time.year, date_time.month, date_time.day)
else: OPEN_DAY = datetime(date_time.year, date_time.month, date_time.day)+timedelta(days=1)
df = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'stooq', OPEN_DAY, OPEN_DAY)

print(df)
```

Comment: It works for my in Spyder as well, there is nothing wrong with the code

Comment: So weird, I even updated pandas wondering if that was the issue, still nothing. Thanks though